# Azure Function - Adding different settings file for different environment in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure function using Visual Studio 2017 and it uses `local.settings.json` file to store database connection string which works fine for my test environment.

Now I need to add database connection string for the staging environment. How can I create a separate `staging.settings.json` file and associate that to my staging build in Visual Studio, so that it will take the `staging.settings.json` file's settings during staging deployment?

I created a `staging.settings.json` and copied the settings file from `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "sql_conn": "Server=tcp:SERVER,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
   }
}
```

Comment: You should have separate azure functions for each environment with corresponding setting assigned via azure portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The staging Function is hosted in Azure, the `local.settings.json` file won't be uploaded to Azure. It's only for local dev.

In Azure portal, your pro Function and staging Function have different Application settings page, so you could directly set your values.

[image]

When we publish Functions with VS, there's a [friendly dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings) to update Application settings. You could also configure the connection strings there. The Remote setting will be upload to Azure.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

local.setting.json is the file which is used for local development only. This file is not deployed to Azure: the settings are taken from Environment while running in the cloud.

So, if you have beta/production Function App, you will configure their settings in App Service Settings.

In my opinion best approach would be to have ARM template based deployment,where you will have two files.

- ARM template file for azure function which include generic variable
- Template parameter file which will have the actual value for the variable declared in the template

For every environment you will have separate function and once you run the build for the function, it will replace the existing settings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the correct way to supply an array of key:value pairs from a template parameter file to configure the Azure Function application settings? My goal would be to have something like:

 - function-app.parameters-dev.json
 - function-app.parameters-prod.json

Answer (score 0):

See my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944352/3563013 Basically, create other tasks to copy to local.settings.json